# How to apply "20% Discount" to specific Customers of a Customer Group in Magento 1.7.2?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have products with a **normal price**(let's say product A costs 20e) and a **group price**(lets product A costs 15e) assigned to my customer group
that I call it "Resellers".

I want to apply **an extra 20% discount to specific Resellers** (not to the whole Reseller group)
in the **group price**(meaning the 15e)

I tried to solve it by creating a "Shoping Cart Price Rule" (I called it "20% Extra Discount") it applies to the whole Customer Group

**How Can I apply 20% it only to specific Resellers and not to the whole Reseller Group for the group price only?**

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible with Magento out of the box.
You can overcome this by generating a coupon that you can send out by e-mail to your specific customers.
or you can try to use an extension [like this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/personal-discount-5570.html).
It's not free, but from the looks of it it might get you what you need.

---

<sub>I'm in no way associated to the extension provider. I just found it on a simple search on the web.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some coding in order to achieve above said, following is the way it should happen.

You would need to hook into an event, ex :

[Changing the price in quote while adding product to cart: magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento/9723026#9723026)

Also in the observer created above you need to do something like

[Add custom discount order in total with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400358/add-custom-discount-order-in-total-with-button)

Now whats above will do :

Let us suppose you create a general rule for 20% discount but do not relate it to any customer group.

What happen is once a product is added to a cart you can check into an Observer whether you want to provide discount to this particular customer.

If yes programmatically add coupon to the quote or order else not.

Please note : there are various other type of event for ex: after moving to checkout etc, in case you do not want to use on adding of product to cart.

hope above helps.